# JavaFX: primary stage visibility and multiple independent stages

Tags: java, javafx

I want to create from CLI console in javafx as many stages as I want and all of them be independent from each other. I know that there can be only one instance of Application, that's why I did:

```
public class BaseApplication extends  Application{
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        //we do nothing with this stage.
    }
}
```

The class for Stage:

```
public class SomeStage extends State(){
   public SomeStage(){
    ...
    show();
   }
}
```

And this the code which runs according to CLI commands:

```
Platform.runLater(()->{
   SomeStage someStage=new SomeStage();
});
```

However, using this code I can create only one instance of SomeStage. If in BaseApplication I do `primaryStage.show();` then I can create N instances of SomeStage but only when primaryStage is visible. How to explain it and solve this dependency from primary stage?

**EDIT**
I found out that when primary stage is not visible and I want to create second instance of SomeStage then Platform.runLater is not called. I mean

```
System.out.println("Point 1");
Platform.runLater(()->{
   System.out.println("Point 2");
   SomeStage someStage=new SomeStage();
});
```

And I see only `Point 1` on the screen and the constructor of SomeStage is not called.

Comment: "However, using this code I can create only one instance of `SomeStage`.". What do you mean here? Every time you call `Platform.runLater(() -> SomeStage someStage = new SomeStage());` it creates a new instance of `SomeStage`.

Comment: @James_D Please, see my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't posted a complete example, so it's difficult to be sure what is happening, but I suspect the JavaFX toolkit is closing down when your `start()` method exits. Hence there is no FX Application Thread running on which to execute the runnable you supply in `Platform.runLater()`. Try calling

```
Platform.setImplicitExit(false);
```

in the `start()` method.

Comment: @Pavel Already read it (a couple of times). It makes no sense to me.

Comment: Again: **I have read that question**. This is not the place to try to explain it more: it's very unclear, and low quality. If you want to improve it, go and edit it.